# convert image path to byte array javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

i want to convert image to byte array javascript, here i have upload image from the gallery , below i mention what i have tried

```
 <input type="file" name="images" id="fileUploadExactequipment" data-value="0" class="imageUpload1"> <span id="lblError" style="color: red;" onclick="imageValidation1(this);"></span></td><td>

var files = $('#fileUploadExactequipment')[0].files[0];
var exactImageByteArray=  fileToByteConverter(files);


 function fileToByteConverter(imagePath){
debugger
var reader = new FileReader();
var fileByteArray = [];
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(imagePath);
reader.onloadend = function (evt) {
if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) {
   var arrayBuffer = evt.target.result,
       array = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
   for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
       fileByteArray.push(array[i]);
    }
}
return fileByteArray;

}
}
```

is this correct or not

Comment: what happens when you try it?

Comment: reader.onloadend this part called very delayed,after completed ramianing function then only reader.onloadend this called @MattEllen

Comment: So it works? I'm not sure what the issue is. Is the problem that it is slow?

Comment: Perhaps you might like to look at filling fileByteArray in a sane manner. No need to push e.a.c.h a.n.d e.v.e.r.y s.i.n.g.l.e entry to it one-by-one.. Perhaps you'll find one of the `.from` methods helpful..https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/from or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Int8Array or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from